# Google Tag Manager API via Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement an automatic mechanism by which, based on data in a JSON file, I can create folders using the GTM API.

Here's an example:

```
json.containerVersion.folder.forEach((f) => {
    var resource = {
      "name": f.name,
      "accountId": f.accountId,
      "containerId": f.containerId,
      "folderId": f.folderId,
      "fingerprint": f.fingerprint,
    }
    var folder = TagManager.Accounts.Containers.Workspaces.Folders.create(resource, accountCreated)

    var updateFolder = TagManager.Accounts.Containers.Workspaces.Folders.update({"folderId": f.folderId}, accountCreated + "/folders/" + folder.folderId)
})
```

In essence, based on a JSON file present on my Google Drive, I retrieve information about the folders, and for each of them, I need to create a corresponding folder in my GTM container. The problem is that both creating a folder and using the update function change the folderId to a different one chosen by GTM, rather than using the desired folderId, such as 16.

How can I associate a custom folderId?